# Multiple Update Queries in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Using Access 2007, I have an update that I am trying to build a script or macro or even just a useful chunk of SQL that I can keep and use whenever I want to run the update...

...I have figured out how to this with an update query, but, I don't want to have to spend an hour or so everytime I want to update...

Basically, I am cross walking office symbols for old to new...but all of the old office symbols need to be updated:

This is the SQL view from in access:

```
UPDATE [Actions Completed - Back UP] 
SET [Actions Completed - Back UP].OFC_NEW = [UPDATE TO:]
WHERE ((([Actions Completed - Back UP].OFC) Like [old]));
```

I used prompts to just run through my list of changes...

THANKS!

yoopersmith

Comment: Can you explain what "Cross walking office symbols for old to new" means exactly?

Can you also explain in plain English what exactly you want the query to accomplish. It is kind of hard to make out from your description of the problem.

Comment: "OFC"...which contains codes for different divisions in my organization...the OFC codes are out of date. So what used to be SYK is now SYSW.  SMC/PK=SYSW, AXK=SMC/PK. 95 old and about 20 new codes.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you create a table that holds the required changes:

```
OldCode  NewCode
SYK      SYSW
SMC/PK   SYSW
AXK      SMC/PK
```

And so on.

You can then easily run an update query:

```
UPDATE tblTable 
INNER JOIN tblNewCodes ON tblTable.Code = tblNewCodes.OldCode
SET tblTable.Code = tblNewCodes.NewCode
```

Comment: UPDATE Actions Completed
INNER JOIN OFCupdate
ON OFCupdate.NEW_OFC = OFCupdate.OFC
SET Actions Completed.NEW_OFC = OFCupdate.NEW_OFC;

This gives me a JOIN not supported error...hmm...BTW, I want to keep the OLD values as well, but sort on the new codes...but I think it will still work...

Comment: You must put square brackets around field names with spaces. You should be joining the main table to the table with new codes, not joining the table with new codes to itself, which is what you have. You do not have to update, if all you want to do is sort, just select fields from both tables:

Comment: SELECT OFC, New_OFC FROM [Actions Completed] INNER JOIN OFCupdate ON [Actions Completed].OFC = OFCupdate.NEW_OFC ORDER BY OFCupdate.NEW_OFC

Comment: UPDATE OFCupdate INNER JOIN [Actions Completed - Back UP] ON OFCupdate.OFC = [Actions Completed - Back UP].OFC SET [Actions Completed - Back UP].OFC_NEW = [OFCupdate].[OFC_NEW]
WHERE (((OFCupdate.OFC_NEW) Is Not Null));

I need to test this on a different table...THANKS all

Comment: UPDATE OFCupdate INNER JOIN [Close Out (all time) Table] ON OFCupdate.OFC = [Close Out (all time) Table].OFC SET [Close Out (all time) Table].OFC_NEW = [OFCupdate].[OFC_NEW];

This is what worked in a new table/database...THANKS!

Comment: Found that there are many OLD OFC symbols that I didn't have...yippee!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to describe your problem a bit more I think, what you are trying to achieve is not entirely clear: explain what you are tracking, how your table is made and what it contains.

Having said that, using a Datasheet form is a very easy way to enter your data (Access 2007):

- click on your `Actions Completed - Back UP` table.
- create a new Datasheet form (Forms > More Forms > Datasheet)
- you can hide the columns you don't want to appear (right-click and select Hide)
- you can lock the columns you don't want to edit by mistake (in the Property Sheet > Data > Locked = Yes)
- You can order and pre-filter the list (put the table in Design view in Home > View, click on the form and in the Property Sheet under Data you can change *Order By* and *Filter*)
- when viewing data, you can also filter the list based on column filters (click the triangle in the column header and you'll get a list of the filtering options, like Excel).

You should now be able to edit your data much faster than having to fill-in input boxes.

There are more interesting things you could do but since we don;t know much about your problem, it's a bit hard to know if it would help or not.

Comment: Ok...I will describe a little bit more detail:

I have a column of data called "OFC"...which contains codes for different division in my organization...the OFC code are out of date.

So what used to be SYK is now SYSW

SMC/PK is now SYSW
AXK is SMC/PK

I have about 95 old and about 20 new